# MySQL Full-text search in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, full-text-search

I am trying to implement a basic full-text search with MySQL.

I wrote this migration:

```
def self.up
  execute 'ALTER TABLE photos ENGINE = MyISAM'
  execute 'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext_photos ON photos (place, info)'
end

def self.down
  execute 'ALTER TABLE photos ENGINE = InnoDB'
  execute 'DROP INDEX fulltext_photos ON photos'
end
```

And here's my model:

```
def self.search(*args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  find_by_sql [ "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE MATCH (place, info) AGAINST (?)", options[:query] ]
end
```

The problem is that this code **always returns an empty array**.

For example:

```
% Photo.find(:first)
=> Photo id: 1, place: "Baceno", info: "Era immerso in erba alta." ... 

% Photo.search(:all, :query => 'baceno')
=> []
```

Comment: This migration script works great, but remember to revert the order in the self.down method, the index must be removed before altering the table back to InnoDB else you get a failure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created a project (Rails 2.3.2, Ruby 1.9.1 MySQL 5.0) to emulate this.  With one record in the database, I got the same results you did.  When I added more records, the Photo.search command found the record.

This could be because "words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match".  [Ref.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)

The 50% threshold does not apply in binary mode. [Ref.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

IN BINARY MODE belongs inside the parentheses: AGAINST ('baceno' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) gem. It's great.

Comment: The ThinkingSphinx Gem works great but be aware that using Sphinx adds  some significant overhead:  e,g, must install Sphinx on server, sphinx searches do not return ActiveRecord::Relations so you must duplicate code instead of chaining scopes if there is more to your criteria than just text search, extra testing setup if you want to test the full text search results, must keep Sphinx indexes up to date with changing data, etc.  

We've been using ThinkingSphinx on a production site for a few years with good success, but the added development, testing, and deployment effort can be a PITA.

Answer (score 3):

The below code runs for my web page and gives correct result in ruby on rails.

```
Adverse.find(:all, :conditions => ["match(related_company,client_name) against (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",@chk])
```

Answer (score 1):

In my test (just in MySQL, not in Rails) when I add the option IN BOOLEAN MODE to the SELECT statement, it seems to return rows.

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE MATCH (place, info) AGAINST (?) IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

I would also recommend using a seperate search product such as Solr or Sphinx for searching.